# Docker PHP/MySQL/Apache container

Tags: php, mysql, docker

Working with a Docker file which includes PHP, Apache, and MySQL.  I was able to get the page to pull up in localhost.  However, I am unable to get the MySQL running.

```
# Use an official PHP Apache runtime as a parent image
FROM php:7.0-apache

# Set the working directory to /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# Install mysqli extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev && \
apt-get install -y libxml2-dev && \
docker-php-ext-install zip && \
docker-php-ext-install xml

# Make port 80 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 80
```

Based on the above, when I attempt to run the following command:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_abcd_123456=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

I receive the following error in the terminal:

```
Unable to find image 'mysql:tag' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for mysql:tag not found.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is that your exact command? Use a real tag instead of "tag". Check the image documentation on DockerHub.

Comment: Well, I did alter the password part.  But other than that, yes.  That is the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) command requires the image name parameter with optional version of the image (recommended).

Use:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_abcd_123456=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
```

to pull the latest mysql image or choose the exact version listed by [supported tags](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

for example:

```
5.7.25
```

or

```
8.0.15
```

In majority cases you should not use the tag with the version `latest` (or skip the version) because that is ambiguous and can give you different versions of the image on two different machines even they used for the build the same [Dockerfile FROM](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) statement or you used the same `docker run` (`docker pull`) command. [Read more](https://vsupalov.com/docker-latest-tag/)

I would recommend always stick to the explicit version number if possible, for example:

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_abcd_123456=my-secret-pw -d mysql:8.0.15
```